# Local addresses unreachable, remote addresses work

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ping

I experienced strange behaviour on my employee's Windows7-Box. I was working via Putty in a local headless Virtualbox (running LXLE and connected via Virtualbox's host-only network adapter) and suddenly got disconnected. While investigating the source of error, I noticed that my network drives also lost connection (to our workgroup's fileserver).

The Windows7 box has an "Ethernet-Adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network" with IP 192.168.56.1, which still answered pings. The Virtualbox-guest system has the IP 192.168.56.101 which did not answer to pings. When pinging the .101 address, most of the time I got the answer "request timed out", but only once I got "Reply from 188.1.33.149: Destination host unreachable".

The latter ping result really puzzles me, as the 188.1.33.149 address is completely unknown to me, and has nothing to do with our LAN. Also it didn't show up anywhere when executing "route print".

I further noticed that I could not ping local addresses anymore, while pinging remote addresses like google.com worked, as well as opening sites in Firefox. After some time, everything seemed back to normal and I could ping local addresses again, but I still have no clue what caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend restarting the network from high priority to low priority (Ex: Start host, then add users), I know its a lame answer but you could try.

If that doesn't work from a previous problem I experienced from accessing localhost could help.

I once had a problem relating to hosting a fileserver real quick on my pc, I tried having the server host on localhost but it didn't work. But when I was doing ipconfig or something it turns out Windows API has an identifier list.

So when looking through ipconfig it appeared my computers address was 192.168.1.200 and the 'identifier' was 0.0.0.0.

But for localhost it said 'undesignated' (I believe this is because I upgraded my computers OS)

But connecting to 0.0.0.0 worked for me so I guess ipconfig could help (Sorry for the long explanation but I felt it needed context)